# C Bit Arithmetic:I'm using (number&1) == 0 to determine even or odd in C - returns only Odd for all inputs

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, operator-precedence, assignment-operator, bitwise-and

I can determine if a number is even or odd in many ways. My aim here was not that - it was to test out a specific bitwise operation. Here's the codelet:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
            unsigned int c;

            while(c=getchar()!='\n')
                    (c&1)==0?printf("Even"):printf("Odd");
            printf("\n");
}
```

My inputs on the terminal are manual and of the type: "1234567890" or "asdf5678", always closed with a \n, which is why I don't need to account for EOF.

The outputs I get are basically strings of "OddOdd..." , exactly corresponding in number to the number of characters typed, as expected, but only returning "Odd" for all characters.

Am I missing out something really basic? As already stated, I am not interested in solving a general problem - I am interested in finding out why this specific piece of code is not working when its logic is sound. Is it something to do with the order of evaluation? (left to right etc) I can't see it being a matter of Operator Precedence as I have enclosed the & operation in brackets, superceding the precedence of ==

Comment: The error is in the `while` statement. `!=` has higher precedence than the assignment. Basically the code says, let `c` be equal to 1 as long as `getchar()` doesn't equal `'\n'`

Comment: "I can't see it being a matter of Operator Precedence" - ah, but it is ;)  See the other responses.  " just didn't want to type it all and make it too tedious to read)"  WRONG!  I strongly suggest that parenthesis can make the intent of the code EASIER to read.  And I emphatically REJECT the notion "fewer characters is necessarily'better'...

Comment: @xiLeon The primary problem in the code you posted is the missing parentheses around the assignment. You **must** have those parentheses. Otherwise the comparison is first, and the assignment gives `c` a value of 0 or 1 based on the results of the comparison. See the answers for additional minor problems in your code.

Comment: @user3386109 - you are absolutely right - I thought I had tried that alternative (brackets around the assignment) but maybe I didn't try brackets around both operations (the assignment AND the bitwise operation) at the same time! Apologies

Comment: @xiLeon Happens to everybody when learning: turning too many knobs at once, and not finding the right combination :)

Answer (score 3):

The expression in the while statement

```
while(c=getchar()!='\n')
```

is equivalent to

```
while( c = ( getchar() != '\n' ) )
```

As the expression `getchar() != '\n'` always yields `1` except when Enter key is pressed then within the body of the loop there is outputted the string literal `"Odd"`.

You need

```
while( ( c = getchar() ) != '\n' )
```

In any case it would be better to write

```
int c;

while( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '\n' )
```

Also in my opinion it would be more readable to write

```
printf( "%s ", (c&1) == 0 ? "Even" : "Odd" );
```

instead of

```
(c&1)==0?printf("Even"):printf("Odd");
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is on this line:

```
while (c = getchar() != '\n')
```

And is due to operator precedence. Specifically, the `!=` operator has a higher precedence than `=`. Adding parentheses shows what is really happening:

```
while (c = (getchar() != '\n'))
```

The condition will be 1, which is odd, whenever the result of `getchar` is not `'\n'`.

To fix this, add parentheses to group the operations correctly:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n')
```

---

This however ignores the fact that `getchar` returns `EOF` on failure. If the `stdin` was EOF, this would loop forever, waiting for a newline that never comes. The variable `c` should be at least an `int` instead of `unsigned int`, to match the return type of `getchar`.

Comment: Very helpful breaking down the assignment for me. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the unsigned arose out of me playing around trying to fix the code (I'm kinda new to all this...) I considered that perhaps it wasn't working because of something to do with the sign bits, silly of course now that I've been shown what the problem was

Comment: "If the stdin was EOF, this would loop forever, waiting for a newline that never comes." --> Disagree that this is certain. After a read failure, the next character read could be '\n'. . Yet agree about c shoudl be int.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica When I say that `stdin` is EOF, I don't mean that `getchar` returned `EOF` once , I mean that `stdin` is end-of-file.